# Saving previous number and adding

Tags: c#

So I'm making this "gambling" program in school our mission is to have 3 dices roll and if the middle dice is bigger than the first one but smaller than the 3rd one you win.

```
    private void BtnKasta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slump = new Random();
        int T1 = slump.Next(1, 7);
        int T2 = slump.Next(1, 7);
        int T3 = slump.Next(1, 7);
        lblDice1.Text = T1.ToString();
        lblDice2.Text = T2.ToString();
        lblDice3.Text = T3.ToString();
        double pengar = double.Parse(tbxPengar.Text);

        if (T2>T1 && T3>T2)
        {
            double satsning = double.Parse(tbxSatsa.Text);
            double vinst = satsning * 5;
            double total = pengar - satsning + vinst;
            lblPengar.Text = total.ToString();
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to make it so that it saves the total from the last "win". For example if I put in 2000 and bet 100 I will get 2400 because 2000-100 + (100*5) but if i press the button again and win again I still have 2400, so how do I make it so that I would get 2800

Comment: Not knowing C# at all, nor the language your variable names are in, don't you need something like `tbxPengar.Text = lblPengar.Text` at some point in your code, say at the point where you press the "Gamble again" button,

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a win-form application, not a web form.

Running debug will show you what went wrong, but let do it via your example.

Let's go through via your example:

> put in 2000 and bet 100 and you win 2 times

```
/*First Time*/
double pengar = double.Parse(tbxPengar.Text);
//tbxPengar.Text = "2000"
//pengar = 2000
double satsning = double.Parse(tbxSatsa.Text);
//tbxSatsa.Text = "100"
//satsning = 100
double vinst = satsning * 5;
//vinst = 100 * 5 = 500
double total = pengar - satsning + vinst;
//total = 2000 - 100 + 500 = 2400
lblPengar.Text = total.ToString();
//lblPengar.Text = "2400"
```

Let see the 2nd time:

```
/*Second Time*/
double pengar = double.Parse(tbxPengar.Text);
//tbxPengar.Text = "2000"
//pengar = 2000
...
```

You could see, on 2nd time, you doesn't update back `lblPengar.Text` to your textbox `tbxPengar.Text`, therefore, the code will just run with existing value (e.g "2000").

So just add `tbxPengar.Text = lblPengar.Text` to the last line will work.

Happy coding